# What is the reason I cannot have an object named Category?

Tags: objective-c

Is the name `Category` restricted in Objective-C?

If I create an object name `Category` that subclasses `NSObject`on a new project I get and error saying `Redefinition of 'Category' as different kind of symbol`.

For example:

`Category.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Category : NSObject

@end
```

`Category.m`

```
#import "Category.h"

@implementation Category

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's already defined in the ObjC runtime.

> /// An opaque type that represents a category.
>   `typedef struct objc_category *Category;`

You can check this by <kbd>⌘</kbd>-clicking on the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an object already created called Category

```
/// An opaque type that represents a category.
typedef struct objc_category *Category;
```

You must redefine the name of your object.